# how to send email notification while message is delivered to DLQ

Tags: jms, mule, esb, mule-component

how to send email notification while message is delivered to DLQ.

I am doing below code

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
        <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
        <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
        <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
        <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />

    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="amqFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <spring:property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.brokerUrl}" />
        <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />

    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<!-- ActiveMQ Connection factory -->


<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ10"
    specification="1.1" username="${jms.username}" password="${jms.password}"
    brokerURL="${jms.brokerUrl}" validateConnections="true"
    persistentDelivery="true" doc:name="Active MQ" connectionFactory-ref="amqFactory"
    numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="2">
</jms:activemq-connector>

<jms:endpoint name="delivery-queue-A" connector-ref="Active_MQ10"
    queue="delivery-queue-A" doc:name="JMS">
    <jms:transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN" />
</jms:endpoint>
```

How to send email notification we retry fails and message is delivered to DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rollback exception strategy to your flow:

```
<rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="10">
  <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
    <set-payload value="Email message body" />
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="..." port="..." user="yourEmailAddress" password="pass" to="someEmailAddress"  from="..." subject="..." responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="my-mail-connector"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="dead.letter">
      <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
  </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
</rollback-exception-strategy>
```

More info:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Rollback+Exception+Strategy